# Обновление строк с подгрузкой

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT min( cts.id ) AS id, cs.value AS cause, count( * ) AS count
FROM `spending` AS sp
LEFT JOIN `causetospending` AS cts ON cts.sid = sp.id
LEFT JOIN `cause` AS cs ON cts.cid = cs.id
WHERE sp.s =1
GROUP BY cts.cid
ORDER BY count DESC
```

Это запрос работает правильно, возвращает он вот такое:

[image]

Что нужно: нужно вставить в таблицу cause в необходимые строки поле count.

Что-то типа такого:

```
UPDATE `cause` SET `cause`.`count` = (
SELECT count(*), min(cts.id) FROM `spending` as sp
left join `causetospending` as cts on cts.sid = sp.id
left join `cause` as cs on cts.cid = cs.id
 WHERE sp.s = 1
group by cts.cid)
```

Но это не правильный код.

Comment: Много непонятного. В таблице cause есть поле count? Какое поле должно быть изменено на значение min(cts.id)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Система такая: нужно связать два запроса - таблицу cause и вложенный запрос, который у вас уже написан. Что-то типа такого:

```
update cause cs 
join (
  select count(*) causecount, cts.cid id,
  from spending sp
  left join causetospending cts on sp.id=cts.sid
  where
    sp.s=1
  group by cts.cid  
) cc on cs.id = cc.id
set cs.count = cc.causecount
```

Вложенный запрос можно заменить предварительно заполненной по этому запросу временной таблицей.

Comment: Большое спасибо. 

Только ваш запрос не сработал, сделал вот так.

    UPDATE `cause` cs JOIN (
      SELECT count(*) AS ccount, cts.cid AS id
      FROM `spending` AS sp
      LEFT JOIN `causetospending` AS cts ON cts.sid = sp.id
      WHERE sp.s = 1
      GROUP BY cts.cid
    )cc ON cs.id = cc.id
    SET cs.count = cc.ccount


Подниму пожалуй ваш рейтинг до 1к. +286. Спасибо!